# There must be a better way (php, string)

Tags: php, string, if-statement, operators

I want to display a user's firstname if they gave us one, otherwise their email.
The code below functions, but I don't like how it takes so many lines, I vaguely recall some way of maybe doing this with OR?
I have (essentially):

```
if ($firstname == "")
{
$name   = $email;
}else{
$name = $firstname;
}
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorter version (PHP 5)

```
echo ($firstname ? : $email);
```

Comment: This is what you get if you run your code in Php 5.3.4: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ',' or ';' in ..."

Comment: I think you need parenthesis around the $firstname. Otherwise it worked great and is definitely the most concise.

Comment: Should've added a comment about the importance of parenthesis with these kind of statements :)

Comment: it's echo (($firstname) ? : $email);

Comment: I know it's a dumb answer, but on my server it works as I've posted, and that's how ti should work. You should be careful with short notation because longer statements tend to mess up, so enclosing every check in parenthesis is a good idea if something's not working as expected.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo ($firstname) ? $firstname : $email;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a less common but sometimes useful construct (as alternative to the `?:` syntax):

```
 $name = $firstname   OR   $name = $email;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was really curious about the syntax for the OR statement (before posting I had tried: $name = $firstname OR $lastname but that didn't work)